# How to zero (or replace) the diagonal of a square matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation

Zeroing the diagonal of a square matrix is an operation I need frequently, but somehow I still haven't managed to find an elegant solution that satisfies all these requirements:

- works with both numeric and symbolic matrices
- doesn't get tripped up by `Infinity` or `Indeterminate`
- doesn't unpack packed arrays
- performs reasonably

So what do you use to zero out your diagonals?  Is there any concise implementation for this at all?

Notes:  Arithmetic with infinities tends to give indeterminates and `DiagonalMatrix` strangely doesn't work with inifinities at all (even though it works with symbols).  Writing an integer `0` into a packed array of reals unpacks it (or generally, trying to write an un-matching type of integer, real, complex).

Comment: Anything wrong with `UpperTriangularize[arg, 1] + LowerTriangularize[arg, -1]`?

Comment: @ciao Looks like it might be exactly the thing I need. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Done - I was surprised at speed...

Comment: @ciao Thanks!  I think this will be very hard to beat, but I'll wait until tomorrow with the accept.  And I know the solution looks trivial, but I never thought of this specific one, and all the other (more obvious) ones have problems.

Comment: Well, It seem I have beat that. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As requested, posting my comment as an answer:

```
UpperTriangularize[arg, 1] + LowerTriangularize[arg, -1]
```

seems to meet all the criteria, quite quick (surprisingly so to me).

Comment: @ciao...very nice (as usual) +1 :)

Answer (score 10):

The following works for a numeric matrix, should be OK for symbolic ones

```
exmat = {{0, 5, 2, 3, 1, 0}, {4, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3}, {4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2}, 
       {4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5}, {3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3}, {5, 1, 4, 5, 2, 0}}; 

MatrixForm[ReplacePart[exmat, {i_, i_} -> 0]]



(*   0   5   2   3   1   0

    4   0   2   5   1   3

    4   1   0   5   3   2

    4   4   1   0   1   5

    3   4   4   5   0   3

    5   1   4   5   2   0 *)
```

Comment: This is a good start, so +1, but it fails on one count: if the array is packed, I'd need to explicitly check whether its type is real, integer or complex, and replace with `0.`, `0` or `0. + 0. I` accordingly.  Otherwise it unpacks.

Comment: OK now  I see what u mean by "packed".

Comment: [Packed arrays are described here.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array).

Answer (score 7):

#### Method one:`` LinearAlgebra`SetMatrixDiagonal ``

```
mat = RandomReal[10, {3, 3}];
LinearAlgebra`SetMatrixDiagonal[mat,Array[0 &, Length[mat]]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[mat]
```

> `True`

#### Method two:`` LinearAlgebra`AddVectorToMatrixDiagonal ``

```
mat = RandomReal[10, {3, 3}];
LinearAlgebra`AddVectorToMatrixDiagonal[mat, -Diagonal[mat]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[mat]
```

> `True`

ps:Note this two method will change the original `mat`.

## Compare with [ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/92670/revisions)'s answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92670/21532)

```
arg = RandomReal[10, {10^4, 10^4}];
LinearAlgebra`SetMatrixDiagonal[arg,Array[0 &, Length[arg]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.406152, Null}`

```
arg = RandomReal[10, {10^4, 10^4}];
AbsoluteTiming[LinearAlgebra`AddVectorToMatrixDiagonal[arg, -Diagonal[arg]];]
```

> `{0.356579, Null}`

```
arg = RandomReal[10, {10^4, 10^4}];
AbsoluteTiming[UpperTriangularize[arg, 1] + LowerTriangularize[arg, -1];]
```

> `{1.41651, Null}`

Comment: cool method +1 !

Answer (score 4):

Just to play with no great idea to solve all issues... and looking  forward to answers.
This respects packed arrays but does not deal with `Infinity` or `Indeterminate` diagonal entries...

```
mat = RandomReal[1, {100, 100}];
sa = SparseArray[mat];
zr = 1 - SparseArray[IdentityMatrix[100]]
res = zr sa
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although perhaps this unpacks but it seems to be fast:

```
replaceDiagonal[m_] := Module[{mat = m},
Scan[(mat[[Sequence @@ #]] = 0) &, Table[{i, i}, {i, Length@m}]];
mat];
```

checking performance:

```
mat = RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}];
replaceDiagonal[mat]; // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.04, Null} *)
```

with a bigger matrix:

```
mat = RandomReal[10, {10000, 10000}];
replaceDiagonal[mat]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.57671, Null} *)
```

How does it compare to other methods posted above for matrix of size 1000 x 1000:

**@thils method**

```
ReplacePart[mat, {i_, i_} -> 0]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.32, Null} *)
```

**@ciao's method**

```
UpperTriangularize[mat, 1] + LowerTriangularize[mat, -1]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.01, Null} *)
```

**All the methods give the same result for an input matrix**

Comment: Why not simply use `Do[mat[[i, i]] = 0., {i, Length@m}]`? Also see [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92666/how-to-zero-or-replace-the-diagonal-of-a-square-matrix#comment252020_92667) about condition when this method doesn't unpack.