# Calculating the reciprocal distance matrix without inflicting `ComplexInfinity`

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

Given a list of coordinates `r` (`r[[i]]!=r[[j]]`), I'd like to know the reciprocals of distances of all pairs in the list, and for the convenience subsequent operations, the trace of the resulting matrix should be all zero. I feel that this should be a frequent need, but I can't do it optimally.

My code:

```
R = Outer[Norm, r, r, 1];
rR = Quiet[1/R] /. {ComplexInfinity -> 0.}
```

But this is not such a good idea as `ReplaceAll` is significantly slower than the other calculations in this code. Is it a good idea to use `For` or `Table` and loop over all indices, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you know all of the `r` values are different, why not just set the diagonal to 0 afterward? Do `UpperTriangularize[#, 1] + LowerTriangularize[#, -1] &@Quiet[1/R]`. [See  here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92666/how-to-zero-or-replace-the-diagonal-of-a-square-matrix).

Comment: Or what's your definition of **distances of all pairs**?

Comment: I think `Outer[Norm, r, r, 1]` should be `Outer[EuclideanDistance, r, r, 1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the coordinates are machine reals and speed is an issue, I would `Compile` a function:

```
reciprocalDist = Compile[{{r, _Real, 2}},
  Module[{R},
   R = Outer[Subtract, r, r, 1];    (* Outer[Norm,..] is not supported in Compile *)
   Map[If[# == 0, 0, 1/#] &@Norm[#] &, R, {2}]
   ]]

SeedRandom[0]; (* for reproducibility *)
reciprocalDist[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 3}]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Theoretically one could cut the speed in half by calculating the upper triangular part.  One could preallocate a zero matrix and fill the distances two at a time with a `Do` loop, for instance.

Comment: Why DV? I can't see what's wrong, other than the stated limitations.  Since no comment, obviously a cowardly troll not sincerely interested in improving the site.

Answer (score 2):

Since `DistanceMatrix[]` is built-in, it seems natural to use it for this problem. Using Michael's example, let me present two approaches:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[0]; (*for reproducibility*)
            pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 3}]];

(* method 1 *)
With[{id = IdentityMatrix[Length[pts]]}, 1/(DistanceMatrix[pts] + id) - id]

(* method 2 *)
DistanceMatrix[pts, DistanceFunction -> (With[{d = EuclideanDistance[##]}, 
                                              If[d == 0, 0, 1/d]] &)]
```

Both should return [image: reciprocal distance matrix]

Answer (score 1):

```
reci[R_] := 
 With[{l = Length@R}, {m = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, {l, l}]}, (1 - m)/(R + m)]
```

If you're before *v10.4*:

```
reci[R_] := 
 With[{l = Length@R}, 
  With[{m = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, {l, l}]}, (1 - m)/(R + m)]]
```

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what was missing from my answer. Did I give too little detail? Or, was it considered incorrect in some way? Either way, would you please elaborate? I'm not trying to complain here, I'm just curious about what I could have done instead.