# Replace element of a matrix with condition

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement, expression-construction

consider a matrix

> $\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}  0 & 0 & 1   \\  1 & 0 & 0 \\  1 & 1 & 0 
> \\ \end{array}\right)$

How do I do a program that does these steps

1-Replace each element equal to 1 by $x_{ij}$

2- Replace elements on the diagonal by 1

After execution the matrix will be formed

> $\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}  1 & 0 & x_{1,3}   \\  x_{2,1} & 1 & 0 \\  x_{3,1} & x_{3,2} & 1 
> \\ \end{array}\right)$

My attempts with the function

```
ReplacePart[MM, {i,j} -> x_] , If and MM[[i,j]]=new
```

But I did not come out with a result, knowing that I am beginning in Mathematica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MapIndexed[If[Equal @@ #2, 1, # Subscript[x, ##& @@ #2]]&, #, {2}]&@
   {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}};

% // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 0 & x_{1,3} \\
>  x_{2,1} & 1 & 0 \\
>  x_{3,1} & x_{3,2} & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
MapIndexed[f[Equal @@ #2, 1, # Subscript[x, ## & @@ #2]] &, #, {2}] &@
    RandomInteger[1, {10, 10}] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
>  1 & x_{1,2} & 0 & x_{1,4} & x_{1,5} & 0 & x_{1,7} & 0 & x_{1,9} \\
>  0 & 1 & x_{2,3} & 0 & x_{2,5} & x_{2,6} & 0 & x_{2,8} & x_{2,9} \\
>  0 & x_{3,2} & 1 & 0 & x_{3,5} & 0 & 0 & x_{3,8} & 0 \\
>  0 & x_{4,2} & 0 & 1 & x_{4,5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & x_{5,3} & 0 & 1 & 0 & x_{5,7} & x_{5,8} & 0 \\
>  x_{6,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & x_{6,7} & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & x_{7,3} & x_{7,4} & 0 & 0 & 1 & x_{7,8} & 0 \\
>  x_{8,1} & x_{8,2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{8,6} & x_{8,7} & 1 & x_{8,9} \\
>  0 & x_{9,2} & 0 & x_{9,4} & x_{9,5} & 0 & x_{9,7} & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) $

Comment: Thank you very much. Can this code be in general? Applied to matrix of size nxn

Comment: @Emad, yes it can be  used for a matrix of  any size.

Comment: @EmadKreem it is always nice to upvote answers !

Comment: @kglr if a matrix in `MatrixForm`  Do not get a result

Comment: +1 ! for nice use of `MapIndexed`

Comment: Ali, thank you for the upvote. @Emad, if the `Head` of  your input matrix `mat` is `MatrixForm` (btw, you can check this using `Head[mat]`)  you should use `mat[[1]]` (not `mat`)  as input to the functions above.

Comment: @kglr see new update

Comment: @Emad, `MapIndexed[.....]&@mat` should work  for the `mat` in your update.

Comment: @kglr Thank you so much. I wish you success and excellence forever

Answer (score 4):

As the diagonals of `mat` are zero, we need only multiply `mat` by a subscripted array and add an identity matrix:

```
(mat Array[Subscript[x, ##] &, {3, 3}]) + IdentityMatrix[3] // MatrixForm  
(*Thanks to David G Stork for IdentityMatrix*)
```

$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & x_{1,3} \\
 x_{2,1} & 1 & 0 \\
 x_{3,1} & x_{3,2} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

More generally, if the diagonals in `mat` are not zero (and using [ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92670/106) to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92666/106) question):

```
mat2 // UpperTriangularize[#, 1] + LowerTriangularize[#, -1] & 
// ((# Array[Subscript[x, ##] &, {3, 3}]) + IdentityMatrix[3]) &
```

where:

```
mat = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}
mat2 = {{6, 0, 1}, {1, 6, 0}, {1, 0, 6}}
```

Comment: Minor suggestion:  replace `DiagonalMatrix[{1,1,1}]` by `IdentityMatrix[3]`.

Comment: @ David G. Stork Thanks! (have modified answer as you suggested)

Answer (score 3):

```
m = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}};

r = # -> Subscript[x, Sequence @@ #] & /@ Position[m, 1];

mn = ReplacePart[m, Append[r, {i_, i_} -> 1]];

mn // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Or

```
f[m_, i_, j_] := 0
f[m_, i_, i_] := 1
f[m_, i_, j_] /; m[[i, j]] == 1 := Subscript[x, i, j]

mn = Table[f[m, i, j], {i, Length@m}, {j, Length@m}];
```

Comment: I imposed that matrix `m` but I did not get the result

Comment: Try again with `m` evaluated (first line)

Comment: Thank you very much. Can this code be in general?
Applied to matrix of size nxn

Comment: It should function for any square matriv

Comment: +1 ! thought of the exact same solution. got scooped :)

Comment: @eldo Thank you so much. I wish you success and excellence forever

Answer (score 2):

```
changeMatrix[mat_] := Module[{dim = Length@mat},
  Normal@SparseArray[
    Prepend[
      First /@ Most@ArrayRules@mat /. {a__?NumericQ} :> ({a} -> Subscript[x, a]),
      {i_, i_} -> 1
     ],
    {dim, dim}
   ]
  ]
```

If, for some reason, your matrices are wrapped in `MatrixForm` (they shouldn't be! -- this should only be used for display purposes), then one can add the following definition:

```
changeMatrix[MatrixForm[mat_]] := changeMatrix[mat] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: if a mat in MatrixForm Do not get a result

Comment: +1 ! the approach here creates a matrix using the rules formed from the supplied matrix. You should not use `MatrixForm` anyways since it is generally reserved for display purposes and not matrix manipulation

Comment: How I can convert matrixform to form

Comment: @march Thank you so much. I wish you success and excellence forever